# jQuery validation for multiple forms with respective submit button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a one page where there are multiple forms such as form_1, form_2..etc & each form contains the respective submit button such as submit_1, submit_2..etc.

Each forms have the records with checkbox to take the paricular action having select all checkbox function.

I want to check in jquery validation that when I click submit button from form_1 i.e. submit_1 then it should check whether user has selected at least on checkbox from that particular form.

HTML CODE :

---

```
<form class="form-group purchase_gift clearfix" name="giftRefund_113" id="giftRefund_113" action="" method="post">
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered marginbottom0">
         <tr>
            <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="selectall" value="113" /></th>
            <th class="text-center border-top-0">Sr. No.</th>
            <th class="text-center border-top-0">Gift Code</th>
            <th class="text-right border-top-0">Price (BD)</th>
            <th class="text-center border-top-0">Status</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
               <input type="checkbox" class="gift" name="giftCodeId[]" id="giftCodeId_667" value="667"/>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center border-top-0">1</td>
            <td class="text-center">56644DEDCF</td>
            <td class="text-right">250.000</td>
            <td class="text-center">
               Not used <a href="javascript:;">Refund</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
               <input type="checkbox" class="gift" name="giftCodeId[]" id="giftCodeId_668" value="668"/>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center border-top-0">2</td>
            <td class="text-center">F448DAB6EE</td>
            <td class="text-right">250.000</td>
            <td class="text-center">
               Not used <a href="javascript:;">Refund</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
               <input type="checkbox" class="gift" name="giftCodeId[]" id="giftCodeId_669" value="669"/>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center border-top-0">3</td>
            <td class="text-center">D76C086174</td>
            <td class="text-right">25.000</td>
            <td class="text-center">
               Not used <a href="javascript:;">Refund</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-right" colspan="3"><b>Total</b></td>
            <td class="text-right"><b>525.000</b></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="form-group marginbottom0 refund">
            <select class="form-control" name="action" id="action">
               <option value="">Select</option>
               <option value="refund">Refund</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="submit" name="giftRefundSubmit_113" id="giftRefundSubmit_113" class="btn btn-success" value="Go"/>
         <div id="errormsg" class="error"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: provide your  HTML code also.

Comment: @smit : I have edited my question with HTML code.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you got the validation plugin set up and working, and just struggling with your specific requirement to see if one checkbox is ticked, or have you not coded anything yet?

Comment: @OmprakashLilhare check the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038756/jquery-validation-for-multiple-forms-with-respective-submit-button?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score -1):

As far I understand your question, you just want to call ajax before your form gets submit. So [view this link](http://js.do/code/123219) which may help you.

```
<form onsubmit="return beforeSubmit();" class="form-group purchase_gift clearfix" name="giftRefund_113" id="giftRefund_113" action="" method="post">
     <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered marginbottom0">
           <tr>
              <th class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="selectall" value="113" /></th>
              <th class="text-center border-top-0">Sr. No.</th>
              <th class="text-center border-top-0">Gift Code</th>
              <th class="text-right border-top-0">Price (BD)</th>
              <th class="text-center border-top-0">Status</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="text-center">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="gift" name="giftCodeId[]" id="giftCodeId_667" value="667"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center border-top-0">1</td>
              <td class="text-center">56644DEDCF</td>
              <td class="text-right">250.000</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                 Not used <a href="javascript:;">Refund</a>
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="text-center">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="gift" name="giftCodeId[]" id="giftCodeId_668" value="668"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center border-top-0">2</td>
              <td class="text-center">F448DAB6EE</td>
              <td class="text-right">250.000</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                 Not used <a href="javascript:;">Refund</a>
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="text-center">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="gift" name="giftCodeId[]" id="giftCodeId_669" value="669"/>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center border-top-0">3</td>
              <td class="text-center">D76C086174</td>
              <td class="text-right">25.000</td>
              <td class="text-center">
                 Not used <a href="javascript:;">Refund</a>
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="text-right" colspan="3"><b>Total</b></td>
              <td class="text-right"><b>525.000</b></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="form-group marginbottom0 refund">
              <select class="form-control" name="action" id="action">
                 <option value="">Select</option>
                 <option value="refund">Refund</option>
              </select>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
           <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Go"/>
        </div>
     </div>
  </form>
  <script>
  function beforeSubmit(){

  var l = document.getElementById("giftCodeId_669").checked;
                  alert(l);
  return false;
  }
  </script>
  </p>
```

Comment: please don't post link-only answers, links can go stale. There's a good chance the moderators will vote this for deletion on that basis.

Comment: @ADyson it may be useful or underused.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer. I'm not sure it helps very much though, the OP specifically mentions wanting to use jQuery validation. This answer doesn't use that, and it doesn't implement the required logic either (specifically "check whether user has selected at least one checkbox from that particular form"), all it does is alert based on one specific checkbox. And it prevents the form from submitting.